# How do I access the phone's camera with React Native iOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been playing around with React Native and I'm confused about what I do to access the camera.

What is the standard way to access the camera on a phone with React Native under iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, React Native doesn't have a way to access the camera. If you feel like wanting to help, React Native has a plugin system that lets you implement Camera support (or any API that isn't provided by default).

https://github.com/facebook/react-native#extensibility
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content

Answer (score 17):

lwansbrough on github has packaged a camera bridge for react native.

https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

However, as stated in document,

> This module is currently in the very early stages of development

Comment: FWIW, the document no longer states that :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade, I've updated the answer because that is no longer stated.